# creating a htaccess redirect that includes a special character

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to create a 301 redirect within my htaccess file, the problem is the links have the (?) special character:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^news/news-item?blue-spares-appoints-stuart-truckel-as-sales-director?$ http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^news/news-item?hugely-successful-scot-plant-for-blue-scotland?$ http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^news/news-item?port-of-workington-takes-specialist-fuchs-materials-handler?$ http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^news/news-item?blue-spares-go-green-with-new-shredder?$ http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/shredders/used-machinery-item?000739:beast-bandit-2860?$ http://www.example.com/machinery [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^about-us/careers/careers-item?project-manager-blue-machinery-london-ltd http://www.example.com/about [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^news/news-item?thompsons-plant-hire-continues-allegiance-to-doppstadt-and-blue-machinery http:// http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/finlay/used-machinery-item?000549:798-double-deck-skin-trommel-screen http://www.example.com/machinery [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/screeners/used-machinery-item?000549:798-double-deck-skin-trommel-screen http://www.example.com/machinery [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/ http://www.example.com/product-videos [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?1 http://www.example.com/product-videos [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?4 http://www.example.com/product-videos [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?3 http://www.example.com/product-videos [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?7 http://www.example.com/product-videos [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What would be the best way to redirect each of these urls to their correct destinations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All characters after ? sign is part of QUERY_STRING, you must add conditions to query string before rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9a-z\-\:]+$
RewriteRule ^product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/? http://www.example.com/product-videos [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/news-item http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/shredders/used-machinery-item$ http://www.example.com/machinery [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about-us/careers/careers-item$ http://www.example.com/about [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^news/news-item$ http:// http://www.example.com/news [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/finlay/used-machinery-item http://www.example.com/machinery [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/screeners/used-machinery-item http://www.example.com/machinery [R=301,L]
```

The adobe rules will match:

```
news/news-item?blue-spares-appoints-stuart-truckel-as-sales-director
news/news-item?hugely-successful-scot-plant-for-blue-scotland
news/news-item?port-of-workington-takes-specialist-fuchs-materials-handler
news/news-item?blue-spares-go-green-with-new-shredder
product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?1
product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?4
product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?3
product-videos/shredders/doppstadt-ak-range/?7
```

And other URLs

See RewriteCond documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond

Comment: what would i do about these type of urls: used-machinery/en/finlay/used-machinery-item?000549:798-double-deck-skin-trommel-screen

Comment: You've added a '?' after some urls and '$' after some others, whats the difference? should they just have a '?'

Comment: @RobMorris  the "?" in "ak-range/?" means the "/" is optional, then "ak-range" and "ak-range/" will be accepted.

Comment: You can change your rules as you need.

Comment: Ahh i see, and what does the '$' sign mean?

Comment: $ matches the end of the string. 

Please read the documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: Thank you for the links, could i be cheeky and ask you to look at the http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hstxy with my sample redirects?